# What is our stance on questions about asking about improving a motor vehicle?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on questions about asking about improving a motor vehicle? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

Example:

> Subject: [Aside from tinting windows, is there any other way to protect a car driver from UV radiations?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/74477/1623)
>
> Aside from tinting windows, is there any other way to protect a car driver from UV radiations? I'm looking for solutions that don't involve the driver itself (e.g., I'm not looking for sunscreen, sunglasses or face mask).

Answer (score 4):

Generally modification questions are on-topic, we've got quite a few under the [modification](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modification) tag. The thing to avoid is asking about product recommendation, we don't generally like those as they can go stale quickly as products and companies come and go from the market.

So, IMHO, the question you link there is perfectly on-topic, wheras I think your other question on the subject is not as it's discussing specific products.

Comment: I'd also throw the [tag:theory] tag in here as well, because I think most of the questions behind it are about understanding vehicles better so as to improve them. Not a hard/fast tag for it, but I think it falls into this category.